# What's the polite and friendly way to ask your lead for a call?

Tags: professionalism, communication, telecommute, teamleader

I am a university student and remotely work for a community, and always communicate with my lead (who is a working lady, and usually busy with her work) on WhatsApp and messenger. Before organizing any local/global event or webinar, I sometimes need to call her in order to discuss different things. I am always confused about how to ask her *if she is free for a call/when she will be free if busy right now* in a polite and friendly manner. Also, she is very sweet and humble.

When she needs to talk or have something to discuss with me, usually she asks "good time to sync up?". How should I ask her the same question?

Comment: You can also copy her way of communicating.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer:

> Hey *lead*. Hope you are doing well. When is a good time to talk? I
>   need to discuss *this and that* with you. Please let me know.

Remember: Nothing is awkward until you make it awkward.

Comment: Thanks, this helped:D

Answer (score 1):

"I need your help about decisions on ... issues. Can you notify me when you have time to discuss them so I can call you. Thank you. "

If he doesnt notify you for a long time ... Go to his office or call you. 
"I hope I am not interrupting are you available ?"
If he says yes,  did you read my mail ?  ....
If he says no, repeat the issue.

If he wont attend you nevermind and do as you wish but before, write another mail

The key is to stay autonomous but redirectable - reprogrammable by your lead.

Since we could not discuss the issue, I am doing ... , ... way. Please notify me if you want me to change any of it.

If your lead is not attending to you work with %50 of your capacity slowly because he or she may come and demand you start over antoher way. You need to stay rested ...

The key is to stay autonomous but redirectable by your lead as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

> When she needs to talk or have something to discuss with me, usually
>   she asks "good time to sync up?". How should I ask her the same
>   question?

She has already demonstrated the proper behavior. Follow her lead.

Just explain why you need her time and ask her when would be a good time to sync up.

This advice is handy in lots of situations. When you want to know a good way to do something in your company, watch how your lead does things, then follow their example.